# sql 2008 disk layout on a budget this is for database mirroring

Tags: sql-server-2008

Guys I'm rolling out a SQL database server that will be used to back Sharepoint 2007. Right now I need some advice on my disk layout. I have two Dell servers that are configured a little differently in terms of storage. The principle server will be using a combination of local storage and san storage. I have to work with what I have the organization is currently all allocated on san storage it was like pulling teeth to even get what I have to work with now. My disk setup on the principle is as follows:

- raid 1 for OS
- raid 10 for logs
- raid 10 fiber on san for high IO databases
- raid 10 sata on san for content databases

My question in regards to the principle server is where should I place the temp db?  I thought about placing it on the fiber raid 10 which will be hosting my high IO Sharepoint SSP databases my only other choice is to move it to the raid 1 os partition which I’m sure you guys will be against.

Now let’s talk about the mirror server it is not connected to the san it is all local 6 15k SAS drives. Now my question is the same do I put tempdb on the os partition or do I leave the os partition and use a single raid 10 for everything? Any help you can provide is much appreciated.

Comment: How many users will be using this sharepoint system?  How large will the databases be getting?  How much IO do you expect to generate from these databases?

Answer (score 1):

tempdb on its own disk if possible.

The SharePoint document storage bit of the content DB (I don't recall what it's called) can specifically be put on the SAN environment if you like.

The rest of your layout is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

There will be about 500 users to start eventually maxing at around 1500. The average content database will be no larger than 20 gigs. I'm not sure how much IO I expect to generate as of right now this is running all on a single virtual machine that is severely struggling to keep up

Comment: This should be edited into your question. As its own answer it could be missed by someone trying to answer your question.